# Webpack просто склеить файлы

Tags: javascript, webpack

Осваиваю вебпак, но сейчас вместо каких-то сложных манипуляций мне нужно просто собрать несколько файлов в один и тут начались сложности. Есть на работе сервис, которому надо подсовывать js скрипты, но там не поддерживается импорт, а у меня там много скриптов и приходится дублировать везде один и тот же код, а уж его обновление превращается в муку.

Я подумал, что у себя создам репозиторий, где буду хранить все скрипты, а в них необходымые утилиты будут по нормальному переиспользоваться через import из соседней папки. А когда мне надо будет залить скрипт в сервис на продакшн я все его  импорты автоматически соберу вебпаком в один файл, который и отправлю в сервис.

Но тут начались нюансы. Во первых у меня много скриптов и для каждого прописыать вручную точку входа как-то не очень, поэтому автоматизировал через glob. Затем оказалось, что вебпак автоматически минифицирует код. Нашел как отключить (optimization: inimize: false). Затем в скомпилированных файлах обнаружил какой-то код вебпака, закомментированный вначале как webpackBootstrap, нашел как отключить (runtimeChunk: true). Но теперь все ещё в выходных файлах остаётся какой-то код, добавленный вебпаком

```
    (window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([[0],[
/* 0 */,
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
```

Как ни пытался его убрать, не получается (максимум, это получалось его сократить если target: 'node'). Мне нужны просто склееные файлы на выходе - каждый файл по отдельности, но внутри с кодом импортов, без лишнего. Может кто помочь? Вот настройки вебпака

```
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: glob.sync('./scripts/*.js').reduce((acc, path) => {
        const entry = path.replace('.js', '').replace('scripts/', '')
        acc[entry] = path
        return acc
    }, {}),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    runtimeChunk: true,
  }
};
```

Comment: Если вам нужно просто склеить файлы, значит вам, наверное, webpack и вовсе не нужен. Напишите простой скрипт, который будет объединять несколько файлов в один, да и всё `cat 1.js 2.js 3.js > result.js`

Comment: Если же вы хотите использовать именно import, то вы никак не сможете избавиться от webpackBootstrap и webpackJsonp, потому что они важны для корректной работы этого самого import (эмуляция пространств имён, обработка множественного импорта и т.п.)